# Get size of Object3D in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this 3D object in my scene:

```
var icon = new THREE.Object3D()

var iconTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/icon.png'),
      iconMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: iconTexture,
      color: 0xffffff,
      opacity: 1
});

var iconSprite = new THREE.Sprite(iconMaterial);

iconSprite.scale.set(14, 14, 1.0);
iconSprite.position.set(Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.75);

icon.position.setLength(0);

icon.add(iconSprite);

icon.position.y = 15;
icon.position.z = 20;
scene.add(icon);
scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```

I manged to get the position of this object:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.getPositionFromMatrix( icon.matrixWorld );
console.log(position.x + ',' + position.y + ',' + position.z);
```

But I can't get the size of that object. I tried something like that:

```
console.log("sizes: "+icon.min+", "+icon.max);
```

But got this output: `sizes: undefined, undefined`.

Is there any way to get the size of that object?

Comment: Do you really mean to ask "What is the size of a THREE.Sprite"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`THREE.Sprite()` has a `geometry` property so you can do:

```
if( iconSprite.geometry.boundingBox === undefined )
    iconSprite.geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
```

and you can get all the info you need from the `.boundingBox` property from its own properties `.boundingBox.min` and `.boundingBox.max`.

Comment: I tried it like that `if( iconSprite.geometry.boundingBox === undefined )
      iconSprite.geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
        console.log("bbox max: "+iconSprite.geometry.boundingBox.max+"\nbbox min: "+iconSprite.geometry.boundingBox.min);
`, but got an error, saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of null`. What am I missing?

Comment: try `if(... boundingBox === null )`

Comment: OK, this sort of worked, I'm getting an object with properties. But I'm getting, for example, max.x = 0.5 and min.x = -0.5. When I tried `var size = iconSprite.geometry.boundingBox.size()` I got this result: `TREE.Vector3 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 0}` So how can I get the exact dimensions of this object?

Comment: you have the min and max bounds of the object and it size. Its dimensions are given by the answer of @bbartosz.baczek except that the y-axis is for the height and the z-axis is for the depth.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was assigned an urgent work to do, didn't have the time to check it. Thank you for elaborated answer! And once again, apologies for the delay!

Answer (score 21):

You could possibly create bounding box from your object:

```js
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(icon);
```

If you have bounding box you can get it's min and max.

`Max.z - Min.z`      ->     height

`Max.x - Min.x`      ->     width

`Max.y - Min.y`      ->     depth

Comment: Cannot edit this answer because "there are too many pending edits", so here's [the correct way to use min/max](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3): `bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x` = WIDTH; `bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y` = HEIGHT; `bbox.max.z - bbox.min.z` = DEPTH. Use intuition on x,y,z vals to get the right dimensions and don't capitalize `max`/`min`

Comment: Today, it's implemented (`'getSize()'`and `'subVectors()'`): https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.getSize , https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.subVectors

Answer (score 2):

```js
const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object)

const xSize = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x
const ySize = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y
const zSize = boundingBox.max.z - boundingBox.min.z

const maxSize = Math.max(xSize, ySize, zSize)
```