# Get properties being fetched in an anonymous function to use them outside of it on the file's scope

Tags: javascript, function

*Hello, I have one doubt:*

The use case is to read a loaded's object width and height and put the container's size to fit that width and height.

Currently I have one function load which we pass in other anonymou function:

```
 let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
            console.log('Slice being loaded is: ');
            console.log(sliceZ);
            console.log('Scene being rendered is: ');
            console.log(scene);

        });
```

Also we do get the info about loaded object's size using `sliceZ.iLength` for width and `slice.jLength` for y.

The difficulty I am facing and I would like some help is this: ***How could we get the parameters sliceZ.iLength and sliceZ.jLength and use them to update container's innerWidth and innerHeight?‽***

I have tried to solve this task by myself. First I looked that we are writting scene.add(sliceZ.mesh); then I saw the console log and I discovered that mesh does not have iLength nor jLength.

I have also tried to add to the scene those properties directly, as:

```
        scene.add(sliceZ.iLength);
        scene.add(sliceZ.jLength);
```

And the web console reports:

```
three.js:8100 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. 3128
add @ three.js:8100
(anonymous) @ InitCanvas.js:50
(anonymous) @ NRRDLoader.js:20
(anonymous) @ three.js:30583
load (async)
load @ three.js:30568
load @ NRRDLoader.js:18
init @ InitCanvas.js:44
init @ logic.js:21
(anonymous) @ logic.js:12
three.js:8100 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. 1760
```

Then I also tryed to put the container's height and width into the anonymous inner function as such:

```
let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
            console.log('Slice being loaded is: ');
            console.log(sliceZ);
            console.log('Scene being rendered is: ');
            console.log(scene);

            this.container.innerHeight = sliceZ.iLength;
            this.container.innerWidth = sliceZ.jLength;

        });
```

Which causes the following log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHeight' of undefined
    at InitCanvas.js:55
    at Object.onLoad (NRRDLoader.js:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:30583)
```

In addition I have tried to use the container variable as it would be local:

```
   // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
            console.log('Slice being loaded is: ');
            console.log(sliceZ);
            console.log('Scene being rendered is: ');
            console.log(scene);

            container.innerHeight = sliceZ.iLength;
            container.innerWidth = sliceZ.jLength;

        });
```

And our web console tells us:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined
    at InitCanvas.js:55
    at Object.onLoad (NRRDLoader.js:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:30583)
```

**Could you help me please?‽**

Also as an image is a good explanation, we would like to get those properties:

[image]

Plus here we see all the code being discussed:

```
// this class handles the load and the canva for a nrrd
// Using programming based on prototype: https://javascript.info/class
// This class should be improved:
//   - Canvas Width and height

InitCanvas = function (IdDiv, Filename) {


    this.IdDiv = IdDiv;
    this.Filename = Filename
}

InitCanvas.prototype = {

    constructor: InitCanvas,

    init: function () {

        this.container = document.getElementById(this.IdDiv);

        // this should be changed. 
        this.container.innerHeight = 600;
        this.container.innerWidth = 800;

        //These statenments should be changed to improve the image position
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.container.innerWidth / this.container.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
        this.camera.position.z = 300;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(this.camera);

        // light

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);


        // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
            console.log('Slice being loaded is: ');
            console.log(sliceZ);
            console.log('Scene being rendered is: ');
            console.log(scene);

            container.innerHeight = sliceZ.iLength;
            container.innerWidth = sliceZ.jLength;

        });


        this.scene = scene;

        // renderer

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.container.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.innerWidth, this.container.innerHeight);

        // add canvas in container
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    },

    animate: function () {

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

}
```

I have also read:

[Get size of Object3D in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758313/get-size-of-object3d-in-three-js)

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Color

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_minecraft

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in assuming you're losing the scope in which `container` exists. It can be solved either by binding your callback function to the current object, or by using closures to ensure you can access to the appropriate container.

Using [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

    // callback code here...
    // use this.container to reference the container

}.bind(this));
```

The `bind` call causes any call to your callback function to use `this` (an instance of your `InitCanvas` class) as the scope of `this` within the callback function.

You can also use a closure to pass the container to the callback function, though this is a little more involved:

```
loader.load(this.Filename, (function(cntnr){

    return function (volume) {

         // callback code here...
         // use cntnr to reference the container

    };

})(this.container));
```

Although it's more verbose, you can see how it would also be possible to re-use the returned callback, rather than defining a new function for each call to `load`:

```
function loaderOnDone(cntnr){

    return function (volume) {

         // callback code here...
         // use cntnr to reference the container

    };

}

loader.load(this.Filename, loaderOnDone(this.container));
```

If you'd like further clarification, just leave a comment with your questions.